# Is there an automatic tool to find "test breaking" check-in in TFS?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tfs

Our leaders decide to revive the unit tests but many of them is broken. I'm appointed to fix it. So, is there a tool or method for TFS which allows to find what and whose check-in broke the failing test?

Comment: Yes, you can set up builds in TFS.  The build workflow includes running tests.  If the workflow fails, TFS can notify the team or even refuse (shelve) the check-in.  (See "Gated check-ins")

Comment: @kedkod: Then why are you asking about TFS?  TeamCity can also send you the details of the CI build, no?

Comment: @David, Yes, I know about it, but our tests are already broken. So, I need to find what check-in broke it.

Comment: @kedkod: Do you keep the history of the CI builds?  Can you see the build in which any given test was first broken?  If you don't have that history, then you're looking for data that the team doesn't have.  You'd need to do quite a bit of manual analysis of the failure reason for the test and the history of that particular component in the code to make that determination.  Neither TeamCity nor TFS can look into the past, they can only look at the data that's there.

Comment: A CI build runs on every checkin. If the build breaks because of the checkin, you'll know it. Your problem is that the build is already broken. But there's no practical way to go back and build every version of the application to find out which changesets would have broken the build and which would not. You have to fix your tests first before you can know which check-in broke them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that there is no off the shelf automated tool.   I assume someone along the line decided to turn unit tests off and entropy gradually took over as time went by.

You could iterate through the checkins since a certain known epoch and reproduce the builds with unit tests enabled.  Depending on the length of the build and the number of builds, that could be problematic.

Most likely you just need to look at each broken test, identify the code that's involved  and do binary searches to figure out when the change was introduced.

But I do wonder... does it matter at this point?  Perhaps someone just needs to go in and fix each of them and move forward.   I don't know just how bad it is for you though.